# DDD Aggregate reference value object mapping to EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I have a `Company` aggregate root and `Agreement` aggregate root in the same bounded context.

I am using DDD approach in my project.

Company and Agreement have One-to-many relationship and therefore I am referencing a company inside agreement using a reference to companies Id.

```
public class Agreement : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid AgreementId { get; private set; }

    public Guid CompanyId { get; private set; }

    private string _number;

    // other fields and functions omitted
}
```

I am using EF core to map these models to database and everything works just fine. Read side is separate so no worries there.

Now, if company name is changed after the company agreement has been finalized, I would like to still have the old name inside my agreement.

So, as I understand, I should wrap reference `CompanyId` inside my agreement, to something like `AgreementParty` value object, which would look something like this:

```
public class AgreementParty : ValueObject
{
    public Guid CompanyId { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

And reference company using this value object

```
public class Agreement : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid AgreementId { get; private set; }

    private AgreementParty _party;

    private string _number;

    // other fields and functions omitted
}
```

But now, I don't know how to map this new agreement model inside EF core entity configuration, so that my domain relationship (Company has many Agreements) persists correctly inside the db.

Hope I explained my problem well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't mess with the value object and simply add a copy of the company name in the `Agreement` class:

```cs
public class Agreement : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public Guid AgreementId { get; private set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get; private set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; private set; }

    private string _number;
    // other fields and functions omitted
}
```

If you need to keep history of the different values, then you could model a `CompanyMemento` and a `CompanyOriginator` tables with a one-to-many relationship *as well as* a one-to-one relationship. Your Aggreement could refer to the memento row:

```cs
public class CompanyOriginator
{
  public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<CompanyMemento> History { get; set; }
  public CompanyMemento Current { get; set; }
}

public class CompanyMemento
{
  public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
  public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
  public DateTime? ValidUntil { get; set; }
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class Agreement
{
    public Guid AgreementId { get; set; }
    public CompanyMemento Company { get; set; }
}
```

However in that situation you would need a separate business model and you would need to introduce a layer of mapping between your EF model and your domain model.

Comment: So you are suggesting something like event sourcing then? As far as the first part of your answer goes, I simplified my model for the question, but I have somewhere around 7-8 properties that have to be "copied" from company aggregate

Comment: Event sourcing is only useful if agreement and company are in different bounded context and you need history for the values. Otherwise, an object value copy is enough. Here I only copied the company name, but if you have multiple properties, join them in a separate class.